# How 'Logjam' attack affects openID since it uses Diffie-Hellman key exchange method?

Tags: java, diffie-hellman, openid

According to the [Diffie-Hellman key exchange get affected by logjam](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/05/20/theres-a-new-problem-with-ssl-called-logjam-heres-what-you-need-to-know/), and openID uses this to establish an association. So how this going to affect OpenID?

Comment: I would checkout [this question/answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89689/what-is-logjam-and-how-do-i-prevent-it?s=1|1.2437) for details on Logjam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logjam is **not** (even remotely) a break of the Diffie-Hellman key exchange method. It is a weakness of the TLS protocol. It affects only sessions, not credentials. It will soon be fixed. I estimate zero impact on OpenID. The "bad guys" cannot do MITM, only governments and ISPs could (in principle) do MITM.

Comment: No longer "in principle". -> Wiki: [Quantum Insert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tailored_Access_Operations#QUANTUM_attacks)

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Damn, man.

Comment: There are plenty of opportunities for even run of the mill bad guys to MITM... Running rogue hotspots in hotels/airports/etc... makes it very easy to achieve...