# How can a RSA-2048 certificate be vulnerable to logjam attack?

Tags: rsa, diffie-hellman, logjam

Most likely I am missing some fundamentals: Our web servers are secured with TLS encryption. We use RSA-2048 bit certificates. The logjam attack targets the DH algorithm. How can our web servers be vulnerable to the logjam attack? Is a combination of both encryption algorithms used?
Also Chrome states for our connection:

- Authentication and encryption with AES_128_GCM
- ECDHE_RSA for key exchange

We removed the support for several cipher suites a while ago and weakdh.org confirmed that we are not vulnerable anymore. Still I do not understand why we were vulnerable in the first place with RSA-2048.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your certificate, it has to do with diffie-hellman parameters [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/693241/how-to-fix-logjam-vulnerability-in-apache-httpd). Whats your web server? have you generated unique/strong diffie-hellman parameters for it?

Answer (score 1):

[EC]DHE_RSA means that the shared secret between the client and server is computed via Diffie-Hellman. In the case of DHE each session has its own DH parameters (DHE = elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman *ephemeral*) which is done to provide [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy). It goes something like this (over simplified):

- Server generates some DH parameters.
- Server signs the DH params with its long term key (i.e. your RSA 2048 key) and sends the params and signature to the client.
- Client verifies the signature for the params against the public RSA 2048 key contained in the servers certificate.
- If the signature is good the client and server use DH with these params to established a shared secret from which they derive keys for the session.

So if your server generates DH params that are too small (e.g. 512 bits) or it supports DHE_EXPORT (or anything else mentioned in the logjam paper), then you are still vulnerable to the attack. You can reference [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/112318/81272) for good discussion on the security of DH params. The key insight is that the long-term RSA key is being used to ensure that the parameters sent to the client were not tampered with and generated by the server. The actual key generation / derivation is done via DH.

(**EC**DHE does not have this pitfall, so any cipher suite with ECDHE_RSA should be fine).